# how to using reflect to create parametric entity

Tags: go, reflect

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Aservice struct {
}

type Adata struct {
    msg string
}

type Bdata struct {
    more string
}

var amap map[string]interface{} = make(map[string]interface{}, 1024)

func (aser *Aservice) Bar(data *Adata) error {
    return nil
}

func (aser *Aservice) Foo(data *Bdata) error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var ser *Aservice
    typeOfService := reflect.TypeOf(ser)
    valueOfService := reflect.ValueOf(ser)

    for i := 0; i < valueOfService.NumMethod(); i++ {

        nref := valueOfService.Method(i).Type().In(0)
        fmt.Println("++", nref.Elem().Name())
        amap[typeOfService.Method(i).Name] = nref
    }
}
```

Currently "Adata" and "Bdata" can be printed correctly

But I don’t know how to store the empty structure pointers of "Adata" and "Bdata" in amap

No idea for the next step

I want to use Method(i).Name() in amap to store the parameters that need to be passed in for the Method

Comment: To get a `nil` value of a given pointer type you can do `reflect.New(t).Elem().Interface()`: https://play.golang.org/p/2Hl_CFtf7Yb

Comment: @mkopriva What if I want the pointer to be nil?

Comment: That is what the code in the playground is producing, is it not?

Comment: I expected the result to be like ```Bar &main.Adata{msg:""}
```

Comment: To get a pointer to an empty struct you can do: [reflect.New(t.Elem()).Interface()](https://play.golang.org/p/T6lrogA9nqP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions in comments :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Aservice struct {
}

type Adata struct {
    msg string
}

type Bdata struct {
    more string
}

var amap = map[string]interface{}{}

func (aser *Aservice) Bar(data *Adata) error {
    return nil
}

func (aser *Aservice) Foo(data *Bdata) error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var ser *Aservice
    typeOfService := reflect.TypeOf(ser)
    valueOfService := reflect.ValueOf(ser)

    for i := 0; i < valueOfService.NumMethod(); i++ {

        nref := valueOfService.Method(i).Type().In(0)
        amap[typeOfService.Method(i).Name] = reflect.New(nref.Elem()).Interface()
    }

    for k, v := range amap {
        fmt.Printf("%s %#v\n", k, v)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bar &main.Adata{msg:""}
Foo &main.Bdata{more:""}
```